# Is it possible to write a log into scr/main/resources in logback?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I have a logback appender:

```
    <appender name="logfile"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/opt/loghome/recon/log.%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log          </fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <append>false</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

I would like to change `/opt/loghome/recon/log.%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.zip` so that the log will be created in src/main/resources in my project. The aim of this is to then have the log on the classpath. Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: The log will only be in the classpath once you rebuild the project. Why would you want a log file to be in the classpath anyway? And why name it .zip if it's not a zip file?

Comment: The aim is to get a set of records from db A. do the same for db B and then use the two logs to perform a reconcilation between the two. The zip part is used to zip older versions of the log up. the format created is .log

Comment: And why would you need the file to be in the classpath to do this. Just open it using file IO. Just because you tell slf4j to name the file xxx.zip doesn't automatically make it a zip file. It will just be a regular, uncompressed log file.

Comment: I have removed the .zip for you :-)

Comment: actually, calling it xxx.zip _does_ [automatically make it a zip](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) file (it's not an slf4j feature, it's a feature of the implementation, logback, which this obviously is, if using the rollingfile+timebased appender). Logback+slf4j is kinda cool like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're using maven.
Maven builds jars/wars/ears whatever
The jars don't contain src/main/resources
In fact this src/main/resources path doesn't exist once your project is compiled.
So I don't really get this idea to put your logs into src/main/resources.

I think its much more "healthy" to include your /opt/loghome/recon/ in the classpath when you're running your project.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Absolutley. Was thinking it would be a nice solution to be be able to build the logs and then interogate them without the need for a directory. But this is probably not going to work. Thanks

Comment: this answer is nonsense, yet the general point is still sound (ie, the question is misguided). A maven project _does_ bundle `src/main/resources` into the jars during the build, and it _is_ in the classpath (inside the jar) after the build, at runtime. (files in `src/main/resources`are at the root of the jar; files like `src/main/resources/com/foo/bar.xml` are in the jar at `/com/foo/bar.xml`). The problem of course is how (or even why) you would write logs  _inside_ of the jar file. Obviously doesn't make sense, so the whole question is unanswerable. (continued...)

Comment: ...but during unit tests, the logs _should_ go into the `target` directory (not `/opt`): just put a logback-test.xml file in `src/test/main/resources` -- which is _not_ bundled into your jars, but rather is just used for unit test configuration. Put your "production" logback.xml into src/main/resources, and optionally use a variable for the path so the file can be output anywhere at runtime -- i.e., instead of `/opt/loghome/recon/log.%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log` , do something like `${com.my.output.dir:-/opt/loghome/recon}`, so that you can (optionally) define the system property at runtime.